# pdf.combined.js gives me error of undefined or null reference in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf

I have pdf.js and pdf.combined.js dependencies in my angular module, it works fine in chrome browser but generate error of null reference in IE 11.

**pdf.combined.js**

```
  if (!PDFJS.workerSrc && typeof document !== 'undefined') {
  // workerSrc is not set -- using last script url 
   to define default location
 PDFJS.workerSrc = (function () {
 'use strict';
  var pdfJsSrc = document.currentScript.src;
  return pdfJsSrc && pdfJsSrc.replace(/\.js$/i, '.worker.js');
 })();

 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'src' of undefined or null reference

for line of code:
 var pdfJsSrc = document.currentScript.src;
```

Comment: use web/compatibility.js

Comment: Thanks, that makes it work.